# Telerik MVC Editor - Ajax Decode

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, kineticjs, telerik-mvc

I am using the following to send a canvas image and contents of Telerik MVC Editor to generate PDF file using itextSharp.

```
               $("#savePDF").click(function() {
                 var editor = $("#Editor").data("tEditor").value();
                stage1.toDataURL({
                    callback: function(dataUrl) {
                        dataUrl = dataUrl.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: "../../Home/UploadImage",
                            data: "{'imageData':'" + dataUrl+ "', 'Text':'" + editor+ "'}",
                            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function(data) {
                                window.location("Home/EportPDF");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
```

The image works great, however the text shows like this:

```
"<strong>Hello world!</strong> <object height=\"1\" id=\"plugin0\" style=\"position:absolute;z-index:1000;\" type=\"application/x-dgnria\" width=\"1\"><param name=\"tabId\" value=\"{84594B7B-865F-4AD7-A798-294A8B0EB376}\" /></object>"
```

Is there a way to get just the text withouth all text starting from object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved it:
First add to the editor:

```
 .Encode(true)
```

get the contents of the editor as encodedValue, using:

```
 var editor = $("#Editor").data("tEditor").encodedValue();
```

Finally in the controller Decode the text using:

```
string comments = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Text);
```